# Drawing convolutional neural networks

Tags: graphs, drawing, latex, scientific-computing, neural-network

Is there any software used to draw figures in academic papers describing the structure of neural networks (specifically convolutional networks)?

The closest solution to what I want is the TikZ LaTeX library which can produce diagrams like this with a description of the network using code (it can't handle *convolutional* layers):

[image: tikz-neural-net] [Source](https://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/)

Other software that describes network structure but does not visualise in 3D are:

- [TorchNN](https://github.com/torch/nngraph)
- [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/graph_viz/index.html)
- [Mxnet](https://josephpcohen.com/w/visualizing-cnn-architectures-side-by-side-with-mxnet/)

The diagrams I want to construct follow a similar pattern, so am interested to know if there exists software more specialised than GIMP/GraphViz/Gephi/InkScape or even Powerpoint to achieve this. It would be great if it was programmable like TikZ.

Here are some examples of figures I'd like to construct (with their sources below):

[image]
[Source](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-%20imagenet-%20classification-%20with-%20deep-%20convolutional-%20neural-%20networks.pdf)

[image: LeNet5]
[Source](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf)

[image: DeepFace]
[Source](http://www.mihantarjomeh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/DeepFace-Closing-the-Gap-to-Human-Level.pdf)

Comment: I'm sure that tikz can produce those graph given enough effort — you can find some amazing examples of tikz usage on [tex.se] and [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/). I could see that the input format might not be what you'd like though. Could you clarify what you mean by “it can't handle convolutional layers”?

Comment: Tikz would be great, though I haven't found an example. The convolutional layers bit is just the layered squares, or rectangular prisms in the examples.

Comment: Do you want to programmatically drive the diagraming, or are you OK laying out the diagram using a GUI interface?  Also do you want it on a specific platform?  Is 3D a requirement as well?

Comment: I need to be able to visualize 3D as shown in examples (no need to be able to view diagram from different angles). 

GUI is fine so long as it is simple to come back and remove a layer or add a layer without it taking too much time e.g. in second example diagram with an A - I want to remove F6 and S2 layers, I should be able to do this by deleting and connections will work themselves out.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wrote a simple python script to draw convnet, with adjustable parameters. 
https://github.com/gwding/draw_convnet

[image: draw_convnet Example Image]

It might be useful to you, if you just need some simple/non-fancy illustration. It copies the style of Figure 2 in "gradient based learning applied to document recognition"

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this and share it.

Comment: @gwding Thank you sir for this useful post. I'm trying to play with the parameters in the code but I'm getting errors related to index out of bounds. Do you have a  more illustrative guide to change these parameters?

Comment: @IbrahimAmer I don't have any written instructions. if you can put your error message into a github issue in that repo, I might be able to help

Comment: @gwding How did you get 18x18 dimensions when performing convolutions with 5x5 kernel? I assume that the text below each step designates what is performed there to get the next image, as can be concluded with Flatten step.

Comment: @AleksandarJovanovic the size would depend on kernel size, stride size and padding. i don't remember the exact set ups. but it is likely due to stride

Comment: i changed the input to 64x64 and it overlaps with the second layer. How do i fix this ?

Comment: @kong you can try to play with numbers in x_diff_list

Answer (score 17):

I wrote an in-browser tool for this as well: [NN-SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html) and you can find the source [here](https://github.com/zfrenchee/NN-SVG). Choose from FCNN layout, LeNet layout, and AlexNet layout.

[image]

Comment: do you have the source on github? I need to fork it, thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/zfrenchee/NN-SVG

Comment: It hangs the PC when I try FFNN with input layers size of 300, 256, 128

Answer (score 4):

This is great: https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet. Solves my problem well, and is written in python/tex.